# A word that describes getting your product 'represented' at a retailer

Tags: single-word-requests

For anyone who's pushing to give a new product some visibility in the market, one way to achieve this is to have your product seen on the shelves of a retailer chain. I am not 100% sure what's the 'proper' way of saying this?

*Listing* a product is as close as I can get. It works with things like online catalogues, but does it work with physically putting the product on a retailer's shelves?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's called getting *[shelf space](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10001424053111903703604576588621006134658.html)*.  See also "[Securing Shelf Space in a Competitive Market](http://www.business.com/guides/securing-shelf-space-in-a-competitive-market-568/)" from business.com:

> When you browse the aisles of your favorite stores, you tend to
>   gravitate toward brands you know. It's no different for retailers and
>   retail store buyers. **Getting buyers to give shelf space to a new
>   product** isn't impossible, but it does require some legwork.

Comment: Product exposure 

Is another option, although it has a wider meaning that just getting space inside the store. So I would say this answer that cornbread ninja posted is the best given the specific context of your question.

Comment: You could talk about *"getting it **on the shelf**"*

Answer (score 0):

***Visual merchandising*** may be (an aggressive version of) what you are looking for.

[**Definition**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/visual-merchandising.html) (from businessdictionary.com):

> The use and manipulation of attractive sales displays and retail floor
>   plans to engage customers and boost sales activity. In **visual
>   merchandising**, the products being sold are typically displayed in such
>   as way as to attract consumers from the intended market by drawing
>   attention to the product's best features and benefits.

Answer (score 0):

A product can be ***displayed*** by retailers.

See http://thescholedge.org/index.php/sijbpg/article/view/76 e.g.